# Adding re-usable content in page from same site

Tags: 2016, reusable-content

I am facing issue with adding Re-usable content in SharePoint 2016. I have a site collection and a sub-site under sitecollection. I have added some content in re-usable content list at sub-site level. When I try to add Re-usable content in page in sub-site, it shows me entries from re-usable content list at site collection level, instead of re-usable content list in same site.

I tried to check Reusable content list ID in web properties of both root web and sub-site. Both webs have correct re-usable content list ID.

Please help me to display content from re-usable content list at sub-site level.

Thanks in advance.